# Is there a way to change Azure Container Registry admin passwords using Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to automate a process to change the Azure Container Registry Admin password(s) using Powershell. I know you can do it using the Azure CLI with the following:

`az acr credential renew --name <registryname> --password-name password`

I just can't locate the equivalent Powershell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`Update-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.containerregistry/update-azurermcontainerregistrycredential?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

```
Update-AzureRmContainerRegistryCredential
      [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
      [-Name] <String>
      -PasswordName <PasswordName>
      [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```